# How to position (offset) absolute element from its current position (NOT from parent)?

Tags: css

*I'm not sure if I'm having a brain freeze or lack of knowledge. This should be super straight forward but I can't make it to work:*

I have a `pseudo` element that I want to be `positioned absolute` *(so it's taken out of the flow and doesn't distort the other elements)*

AND

I want the **pseudo element** to be **offset from its CURRENT position**, eg just 20px to the left from where it is now.

I **CAN'T** use the typical positioning offset from the parent via `left: __px` because it's causing problems on different screen sizes.

Could someone please enlighten me how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/pcsa2ow6/

```css
.x_cta_error_msg {
 line-height: 1.5; 
 background-color: lightgreen;
 padding: 10px 15px 10px 45px;
 height: 50px
}

.x_cta_error_msg::before, .x_simple_cta_error_msg::before {
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
 font-weight: 900; 
 content: "\f06a";
 font-size: 18px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">

  <div class="x_cta_error_msg">
    Some text that will be here to showing to the user as an info through the journey of making a booking. 
                           
       </div>
        </div>
        
        
<!-- just loading the fontawesome icon -->        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: position:relative need to go to `x_cta_error_msg` and then somply use left:Xpx on the icon

Comment: Hi Temani  I believe what you mean would be the typical way of setting the parent to relative and then the pseudo to absolute and define the location from the PARENT (i.e. left: _px). However, this is not what I want. I need to set the position of the pseudo from its absolute position not from the parent.

Comment: and why? what wrong in setting the parent position:relative?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the parent = relative, but then you have to set the pseudo distance (left) from the parent and if the parent expands in size depending on screen size then your child will always be relative to that, whilst I want the child (pseudo) to be bound to the text I have in the div. So with the solution below (transform) the pseudo will always be relative to the text and the parent can expand as it wish, so it's more robust regarding mobile responsiveness.

Comment: you are overcomplicating a simple task, if the parent expand it means that the text inside will follow since it's its content and no the transform solution is not robust because it rely on something called *static position* that may behave differently based on each case.

Comment: I thought I may be, but I haven't a simpler solution to the problem. I have amended the fiddle so you better understand: https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/pcsa2ow6/11/     if you expand the window width, you will see how the icon is tied to the left, while the text is getting further away from the icon.

Comment: + at some point the text will break into the second row and then start under the icon. So it would be best to set some padding from the left (for the text) and then distance the icon from the text, to keep the area under the icon clean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `transform: translateX(-150%);` to move it to the left where `150%` means `150%` its own width.

```css
.x_cta_error_msg {
 line-height: 1.5; 
 background-color: lightgreen;
 padding: 10px 15px 10px 45px;
 height: 50px
}

.x_cta_error_msg::before, .x_simple_cta_error_msg::before {
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; 
 font-weight: 900; 
 content: "\f06a";
 font-size: 18px;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translateX(-150%);
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">

  <div class="x_cta_error_msg">
    Some text that will be here to showing to the user as an info through the journey of making a booking. 
                           
       </div>
        </div>
        
        
<!-- just loading the fontawesome icon -->        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Although `position:relative` should work for you along with `left` as stated in comment.

Comment: PERFECT! It also works with px. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much, really appreciate your fast help!

Comment: and no, the standard solution position: relative on the parent and left on the child wouldn't work for me it's not great for responsiveness as it's parent dependent, which can be become difficult if the parent size isn't fixed.

Answer (score 1):

don't use positionning at all and rely on normal flow:

```css
.x_cta_error_msg {
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 45px;
  height: 50px;
  text-indent:-20px; /* all what you need */
}

.x_cta_error_msg::before,
.x_simple_cta_error_msg::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f06a";
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: relative">

  <div class="x_cta_error_msg">
    Some text that will be here to showing to the user as an info through the journey of making a booking
    Some text that will be here to s.

  </div>
</div>


<!-- just loading the fontawesome icon -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: this seems indeed even easier! However, for some reason it doesn't work on my website, but hank you anyway! Will try to keep this in mind as well (to just remove all positioning).